# What is wrong with this false proof of $\pi=0$?

Tags: integration, fake-proofs

Consider the integral
$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$$
Now, from the standard integral results we know,
$$\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x=\arctan(x)+c$$
So,
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x=\arctan(1)-\arctan(-1)=\frac{\pi}{4}-(-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Now, if you are bored and just doing random things you might evaluate this integral in a roundabout way by the substitution $u=\dfrac{1}{x}$.

This gives the bound for the integrals as $u=\dfrac{1}{-1}=-1$ to $u=\dfrac{1}{1}=1$ and the differential becomes $\mathrm{d}{x}=\dfrac{-1}{u^2}\mathrm{d}{u}$. So, the integral becomes
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{u^2}+1}\frac{-1}{u^2}\mathrm{d}u = -\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{u^2+1}\mathrm{d}u=-I$$.

Now, $$I=-I  \implies 2I=0\implies \pi=0$$.

So, there is your false proof.

I think that the problem in the proof comes when we do the substitution $x=\dfrac{1}{u}$. But, I dunno what it is. Does it have to do something with the continuity of the substitution, or is it something else.

Comment: Think about the bounds. What happens when $x\to0$?

Comment: @PeterForeman So, if the substituted variable becomes discontinuous at some point where the original variable was continuous so we cant proceed with the integration with substitution. Am I correct to infer that?

Comment: You can change limits, if variable is undefined somewhere. 1/x is discontinuous (to say more precisely) in range [-1,1]. For this you have to seperate into two integrals $\int_{-1}^{0^-} + \int_{0^+}^1$

Comment: BTW, with TeX and MathJax, you want the punctuation inside the double dollar sign, since that ends the line.  Otherwise, you end up with the punctuation all by itself on the next line.  (With a single dollar sign, you want the punctuation outside, since the punctuation isn't part of the math.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should actually get is that
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac1{x^2+1}dx+\int_{-1}^0 \frac1{x^2+1}dx$$
Then the substitution will give
$$I=-\int_\infty^1 \frac1{u^2+1}du-\int_{-1}^{-\infty} \frac1{u^2+1}du$$

Answer (score 4):

The flaw is in changing the integration interval.

$$-1\le x\le1\iff \frac1x\le-1\lor \frac1x\ge 1$$